# Paginação Manual no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, framework, paginação

Estou tentando utilizar a paginação manual do Laravel 5.1 porque tenho uma query que precisa ser escrita com o select do DB, porém a paginação não funciona! Ele me retorna todos os dados na tela sem paginação.

Segue:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;

$my_query = DB::select('
    ;WITH 
    UL1 As (SELECT E.ClientStoreID, MAX(E.InsertDate) AS data
    FROM ClientStoreMediaExecuted AS E, ClientStore AS S
    WHERE E.ClientStoreID = E.ClientStoreID
    AND S.ClientID=?
    GROUP BY E.ClientStoreID)

    SELECT CS.* FROM UL1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN  ClientStore AS CS 
    ON (CS.ClientStoreID = UL1.ClientStoreID)
    WHERE CS.ClientID=?
    AND CS.IsActive=1', [$id, $id]);


$paginator = new Paginator($my_query, count($my_query), $perPage, $currentPage, [
        'path'  => Request::path(),
        'query' => $my_query,
        'fragment' => array_slice($my_query, $perPage),
        'pageName' => 'page'
]);
```

Comment: Você não pode usar a função `paginate()` do Laravel ?

Comment: Não posso usar. A função paginate() do Laravel só funciona quando a query não tem nenhum group by e também não funciona com o DB::select só com o DB::table e o Eloquent. Vou editar a pergunta e colocar a query.

Comment: Qual o valor da variável `$perPage` ?

Comment: o valor é 20 por página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi pessoal eu consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator; //Manually pagination

$total; //total de linhas da query

$my_query; //query

$quant = 20; //total por página

//paginação
$currentPage = Request::get('page', 1); //pega a página
$query_slice = array_slice($my_query, ($currentPage - 1) * $quant, $quant); //fatia o resultado da query
$paginacao = new LengthAwarePaginator($query_slice, $total, $quant, $currentPage); //chama a paginação
$paginacao->setPath(Request::url()); //passa a url

return $paginacao;
```