# Criar paginação automática com laravel e jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Preciso criar uma paginação manual no laravel. Não entendi muito bem a lógica desse tópico:

[Paginação Manual no Laravel 5.1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78517/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-manual-no-laravel-5-1)

Mas estou precisando fazer com que ele crie as páginas automáticas. Não manual.
Veja o exemplo que fiz. Ele até funciona só que não é automático:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
 $qtd = $request['qtd'];
 $page = $request['page'];
 Paginator::currentPageResolver
(function () use ($page)
{
   return $page;
});
 $clientes = Clientes::paginate($qtd);
 $clientes = $clientes->appends
 (Request::capture()->except('page'));
 return response()->json
 (['clientes'=>$clientes], 200);
}
```

Nesta saída ele até cria a quantidade de páginas do tipo last_page = 5. Até 5 páginas. Mas preciso implementar isso no javascript:

JAVASCRIPT QUE TRAGO A PAGINAÇÃO:

```
 function retorna_cliente(valor)
 {
var id_cliente = "";
var nome_cliente = "";
var data_nascimento_cliente = "";
var telefone_cliente = "";
var celular_cliente = "";
var cpf_cliente = "";
var cnpj_cliente = "";
var endereco_cliente = "";
var email_cliente = "";
var cliente = "";
var mostra_dados_pessoa = "";
var container_mostra_cliente = $('.mostra_clientes');
var itemHTML = "";
var mensagem_cliente = "Nenhum cliente encontrado";
var quantidade = $("#qtd").val();
var pagina = 5;
var total_page = "";
var page = "";

if (valor == null)
{
  total_page = 1;
}
else if (valor == 'proximo')
{
  page = 1;
  total_page = page + 1;
}
else if (valor == 'anterior')
{
  page = 1;
  total_page = page - 1;
}

$.ajax({
  url: url_base + "clientes?qtd=" + quantidade + "&page=" + total_page,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data)
  {
    var retorno = data.clientes.data;
    if (retorno == 0)
    {
      $('.classe-cliente').css('display','none');
      $('.cliente-error-registro').css('display','block');
      $('.cliente-error-registro .mensagem-erro').html(mensagem_cliente);
    }
    else
    {

      $.each(data, function(key,item) {

        let current_page = item.current_page;
        let last_page = item.last_page;
        let next_page_url = item.next_page_url;
        let prev_page_url = item.prev_page_url;
        let clientes = item.data;

        if (next_page_url == null)
        {
          $('.actionBar').html("<a id='btn-prox-pagina-cliente' title='Próxima Página' class='buttonNext btn btn-success' style='display:none;'>Próxima Página >></a><a id='btn-pagina-anterior-cliente' title='Pàgina Anterior' class='buttonPrevious btn btn-primary' style='display: block; clear:both; width:150px; float: left;'><< Página Anterior</a>");
        }
        else if (prev_page_url == null)
        {
          $('.actionBar').html("<a id='btn-prox-pagina-cliente' title='Próxima Página' class='buttonNext btn btn-success'>Próxima Página >></a><a id='btn-pagina-anterior-cliente' title='Pàgina Anterior' class='buttonPrevious btn btn-primary' style='display: none;'><< Página Anterior</a>");
        }
        else if (next_page_url != null || prev_page_url != null)
        {
          $('.actionBar').html("<a id='btn-prox-pagina-cliente' title='Próxima Página' class='buttonNext btn btn-success'>Próxima Página >></a><a id='btn-pagina-anterior-cliente' title='Pàgina Anterior' class='buttonPrevious btn btn-primary'><< Página Anterior</a>");
        }

        for (var i in clientes) {

          id_cliente = clientes[i].id;
          nome_cliente = clientes[i].nome;
          telefone_cliente = clientes[i].telefone;
          cpf_cliente = clientes[i].cpf;
          cnpj_cliente = clientes[i].cnpj;
          endereco_cliente = clientes[i].endereco;
          email_cliente = clientes[i].email;
          cliente = clientes[i].cliente;

          if (cpf_cliente == null)
          {
            mostra_dados_pessoa = cnpj_cliente;
          }
          else
          {
            mostra_dados_pessoa = cpf_cliente;
          }

          itemHTML += "<tr>";
          itemHTML += "<td><th><input type='checkbox' value='" +  id_cliente + "' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/></th></td>";
          itemHTML += "<td>" + nome_cliente + "</td>";
          itemHTML += "<td>" + telefone_cliente + "</td>";
          itemHTML += "<td>" + mostra_dados_pessoa  + "</td>";
          itemHTML += "<td>" + endereco_cliente + "</td>";
          itemHTML += "<td>" + email_cliente  + "</td>";
          itemHTML += "<td>" + cliente  + "</td>";
          itemHTML += "</tr>";
        }

      });
      container_mostra_cliente.html(itemHTML);
    }

  },
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
 }
```

Comment: Porque precisa criar no Javascript se a Paginação já vem com os dados prontos. !!!? se ela já faz o calculo e te retornar os valores você não poderia utilizar esses valores ?

Comment: Estou fazendo uma API RestFull e preciso que seja assim

Comment: Eu sei que o laravel trabalha com o paginate lá. Mas no momento eu não estou usando views. Aguma sugestão?

Comment: como assim você não está usando view?

Comment: Não uso view. Na verdade o laravel só faz a consulta entende? É uma API. O frontend eu uso separado. No laravel eu só insiro as informações, faço consulta etc

Comment: Quando você dá o retorno do paginate por exemplo se pode utilizar os dados no rest da sua api. usar angular seria também um boa opção. Existe caminhos mais fácil.  fazer html gerada pelo javascript acredito ficar um trabalho dificil de dar manutenção.

Comment: Putz. Mas daí vou ter que fazer novamente! Já é muito tempo jogador fora...kkkkk. Nem que eu resolva isso pelo próprio javascript. Como que poderia fazer?